# Bounding probabilities of a random variable with Markov and Chebyshev and Hoeffding

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, upper-lower-bounds

I am trying to get a better understadning of Markov, Chebyshev and Hoeffding's bounds. I am therefore looking into a problem to give me the understanding.

In the problem I am facing 15 assignments are graded on a 0-100 scale. And where it is assumed that each assignment is an independent sample of the authors knowledge of the material and that all scores are sampled from the same distribution. $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{15}$ denote the scores and $\hat{Z}=\frac{1}{15} \sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i}$ their average. $p$ denotes the unknown expected score, so that $\mathbb{E}\left[X_{i}\right]=p$ for all $i$.

And I am to find the maximal value $z$,such that the probability of observing $\hat{Z} \leq z$ when $p=60$ is at most $\delta=0.05$ for the three types of bound.

***EDIT:** I've gotten an answer to markov part. The Chebyshev and the Hoeffding is still partly unanswered*

For the Markov bound I've used the hint that $\hat{Q} = 100 - \hat{Z} = 40$
$P(\hat{Z} \geq  z) \leq  z = \frac{\frac{1}{15}*40}{0.05} = 53,3$

***Chebyshev***
For Chebyshev it is suggested that you can use the fact that for a random variable $X \in[a, b]$ and a random variable $Y \in\{a, b\}$ with $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Y]$ we have $\operatorname{Var}[X] \leq \operatorname{Var}[Y]$.
Likewise it is suggested that one determines what should be the values of $\mathbb{P}(Y=a)$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y=b)$ in order to get the right expectation and afterwards that one obtain a bound on the variance.

I am however not sure how $\mathbb{P}(Y=a)$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y=b)$ relates to variance in the Chebyshev inequality.
Could you perhaps guide me in some direction w.r.t. getting clearer about how to find $a$ and $b$. Thanks a lot.

I am trying to understand how the Chebyshev bound can be calculated once, I've found the values for P(Y = a) and P(Y = b). More specificially I have some problems understanding the relationship between $P(\hat{Z} \geq z)$ and  how it relates to Y
In the comments it was suggested to use
$V\left( \frac{1}{15} \sum X_{i}\right)=\frac{1}{15^{2}} V\left(\sum X_{i}\right)=\frac{1}{15} X_{i}$ for Chebyshev.

In order to re-write $P(\hat{Z} \geq z)$ so that we can consider the variable,
I've rewritten both-hand sides of the expression.

$P(\hat{Z} \geq z) =
P(\frac{1}{15} \sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i} \geq z) =
P(\frac{1}{15} \sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i} - E[\hat{Z}] \geq z - E[\hat{Z}])=$
$ 1 - P(\frac{1}{15} \sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i} - E[\hat{Z}] \leq z - E[\hat{Z}]) \leq $

$1 - P(|\frac{1}{15} \sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i} - E[\hat{\frac{1}{15}, \sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i}}]| \leq z - E[\hat{\frac{1}{15} \sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i}}]) \leq $

$1 - \frac{Var(\frac{1}{15} \sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i})}{(z - E[\hat{\frac{1}{15} \sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i}}])^2} \leq 1 - \frac{Var(Y)}{(z - E[Y])^2} = 0.05$

We now want to insert values for Y.

We have for the variance that $E[Y^2]−E[Y]^2=2400 $

And for the denominator that

$(z - (100* 0.6 + 0 *0.4))^2 = z^2 -180z + 3600$

We re-arange the equation:

$1 - \frac{Var(Y)}{(z - E[Y])^2} = 0.05 \iff$

$z^2 -180z + 3600 - 2400 = 0.05z^2 -9z +180 \iff$

$0,95z^2 -171z + 1020 = 0 \iff$

$z_1 = 173.8231$
$z_2 = 6.1769$

The max value of z is therefore 6,17. This is the case since $z_1$ is outside of the score interval from 0-100. And provides a mindless value for z.

Could this be right though?
In the assignment they want us to discuss:
"*Which of the three inequalities provide a non-vacuous value of z? (You
know without any calculations that for any $z < 0$ we have $P(Z ≤z) = 0$,
so any bound smaller than 0 is useless.)*"

My value isn't smaller than 0, so I figure the reasoning here mentioned doesn't apply.

***Hoeffdings***
For the Hoeffdings bound I am a bit unsure of the relationship between the average $\hat{Z}$ and $X_i$. I've tried to rewrite the formula in a similar style to what I did in the Chebyshev case. Like this:

$P(\frac{1}{15} \sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i} \geq z )=$

$P(\sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i} \geq z * 15 ) =$

$P(\sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i} - \mu \geq z * 15 - \mu ) =$

$P(\sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i} - E[\hat{Z}] \geq z * 15 - E[\hat{Z}]) =$

$1 - P(\sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i} - E[\hat{Z}] \leq z * 15 - E[\hat{Z}]) \leq$

$ 1 - e^{-2*15*(z*15 - 60)^2} = 0,05 \iff$

$ln(1) -30 * (225z - 3600) = ln(0,05) \iff$

$-6750z + 108000 = ln(0,05) - 108000 \iff$

$-6750z  = ln(0,05) - 108000 \iff$

$-6750z = -ln(0,05) + 3600   \iff$

$z = (-ln(0,05) + 3600)) / 450 = 16,01$

Because of the result I am however unsure if the way I rewrite it is legitimate, considering that the value of the left hand side within the $P(\hat{Z} \geq z)$ doesn't mean a change in the bound as such. Furthermore I am not sure if I have understood the relationship between the average $\hat{Z}$ and the r.v $X_i$ correctly in Hoeffdings formula.

Comment: How exactly did you use Markov's inequality? I cannot immediately see how you arrived at that value. Using Markov's inequality directly on $P(\hat{Z} \leq z) = 1 - P(\hat{Z} \geq z)$, I retrieve $z \leq 63.1$.

Comment: Interesting question. I used it as specified above with $P(\hat{Z} \leq  z) \leq  \frac{E[\hat{Q}]
}{z}$  where $z$ corresponds to the $\epsilon$ in markovs stand inequality. I didn't have a right hand side equal to yours. I shall try with that inequality.

Comment: I have now tried to see if I can reproduce your inequality. I might be not understand Markovs inequality well enough since I was not able to get what you got. As I have just stated my appraoch was to use that $P(\hat{Z} \leq  z) \leq  \frac{E[\hat{Q}]
}{z} = 0.05 $ where $\hat{Q} = 100 - \hat{Z} $ I am not sure of if that should make up for your way of writing it i.e. (1 - P).

Comment: As far as I know, Markov's inequality states that $P(\hat{Z} \geq z) \leq E[\hat{Z}]/z$.

Comment: Yeah I see that is correct. But I thought that by using the hint about $\hat{Q}$ would actually make $P(\hat{Z} \leq  z) \leq  \frac{E[\hat{Q}]
}{z} = 0.05 $ equivalent to writing $P(\hat{Q} \geq z) \leq  \frac{E[\hat{Q}]
}{z} = 0.05 $. 

I am unsure about how you rewrite $P(\hat{Z} \leq z)=1-P(\hat{Z} \geq z)$, such that you find $z$. I end up with the following expression when applying markov, but don't know how to isolate z: $P(\hat{Z} \geq  z) =  1 - P(\hat{Z} \leq  z) \leq 1 -\frac{E[\hat{Z}]
}{z} = 0.05 \iff  1 - P(\hat{Z} \leq  z) \leq 1 - \frac{60
}{z} = 0.05$

Comment: Try to use the inequality exactly as I stated it...

Comment: Ah.. Now I get the same result as you do. And this is without using their hint at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y$ be a random variable that equals 100 with probability 0.6 and 0 with probability 0.4. This random variable has an expectation of 60 and a variance of $E[Y^2]-E[Y]^2 = 2400$. According to the provided hint, the variance of the random variable $X$ corresponding to each $X_i$ is thus bounded by 2400.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @dshin , but I am unsure of as to why it would be the case that Y is a random variable that equals 100 with probability 0.6 and 0 with probability 0.4 , is that because we just know that the probability of scoring 0 and 100 is no lower or no higher than 0.4 and 0.6 respectively?

I am unsure of why you would get 2400 in the $E[Y^2] - E[Y]^2 = 2400$ ,   $E[Y]^2$ doesn't equal zero but (100*0.6 + 0*0.4)^2 = 2400, right?

Comment: The hint only applies when $X$ and $Y$ have equal expectations and when $X$ and $Y$ have equal min/max values. Any other choice of $Y$ would not allow you to apply the hint. The 2400 value I computed should be correct.

Comment: Aha, I think I understnad the first part of your answer.

The second part I am still not sure of. This might be due to a lack of proper understanding of expectations. I calculate it like this w.r.t Y: $E[Y^2] =  100^2 * 0.6 + 0^2 * 0.4 = 6000$, and $E[Y]^2 = (100*0.6 + 0*0.4)^2 = 2400$ we get $E[Y^2] - E[Y]^2 = 3600$, or am I misunderstanding somehting about expected values?

Comment: $(100 \cdot 0.6 + 0 \cdot 0.4)^2 = 3600$

Comment: You are right! Thanks. Let me try to get back to your other comment.

Comment: If I am now to apply that to Cheybshevs formula , am I then to just insert Y instead of $\hat{Z}$ such that  $P(|\hat{Z} - E[\hat{Z}]| \geq z) \leq \frac{Var(Y)}{z^2} = 0,05 \iff z = \sqrt(\frac{2400}{0,05}) = \sqrt(48000) = 219$ 

Which seems to be a bit off considering the score of 0-100, although the exercise states that one of the bounds will give a mindless value.

Comment: or do we need to rewrite
$P(\hat{Y} \geq z)$ before hand such taht
$P(\hat{Y} - E[\hat{Y}] \geq z - E[\hat{Y}]) \leq \frac{Var(Y)}{(z- E[\hat{Y}])^2} $

By doing so the visible relationship stated between $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$ , and $E[\hat{Z}]$ isn't kept. Furthermore $E[\hat{Z}]$ is unknown so I woudlnt know how to include it in the expression.

Comment: Take care to bound the variance of $\hat{Z}$ correctly. Use $V(\frac{1}{15} \sum X_i) = \frac{1}{15^2} V(\sum X_i) = \frac{1}{15} X_i$, because $X_i$ are independent. You will find a sharper bound than the one derived using Markov's inequality.

Comment: I am not entirely sure why $V\left(\frac{1}{15} \sum X_{i}\right)=\frac{1}{15^{2}} V\left(\sum X_{i}\right)=\frac{1}{15} X_{i}$ is the case. You use linearity of expectation to get to step 2. But how come you get $\frac{1}{15^2}$ and in step three, how come the Variance is cancelled out by the the sum of the r.v.s $X_i$  ?

Comment: For getting at the second step I think you use the property that $Var(cX) = c^2Var(X)$. For the third step however I am still a bit unsure of what is going on.

Comment: We simply have $V(\sum_{i=1}^{15} X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{15} V(X_i) = 15 V(X_i)$, because they are identically distributed.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, but where does it fit? I have here tried to re-write both sides.
$P(\hat{Z} \geq z) =
P(\frac{1}{15} \sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i} \geq z) = \\
P(\frac{1}{15} \sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i} - E[\hat{Z}] \geq z - E[\hat{Z}])\leq \\ 
P(|\frac{1}{15} \sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i} - E[\hat{\frac{1}{15}, \sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i}}]| \geq z - E[\hat{\frac{1}{15} \sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i}}]) \leq \frac{Var(\frac{1}{15} \sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i})}{(z - E[\hat{\frac{1}{15} \sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i}}])^2}
$Your comment fits the numerator. But how to calculate the denominator, when $X_i$ can be any of the scores?

Comment: I guess you could then write the denominator as $E[\hat{\frac{1}{15} \sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i}}])^2 = E[X_1]$ due to the indepedence so you would have 

$ \leq \frac{Var(\frac{1}{15} \sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i})}{(z - E[\hat{\frac{1}{15} \sum_{i=1}^{15} X_{i}}])^2}
\leq \frac{Var(Y)}{(z-E[Y])^2}$ as stated due to the hint of $E[Y] = E[X]$ max values of a and b.